# object Object does not fit the Control specification

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to debug this code and i tried to follow an example that works perfectly and i can get the chart and graphs to display without wrapper but once i make the change it falls apart ----[object Object] does not fit the Control specification.

WORKING code that puts all 3 on same view:
    
    
    Project 1: Spreadsheet display working

```
    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.

    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart', 'table']      
    });

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(sendQuery);

    // Construct and send a query to Google Spreadsheet
    function sendQuery() {

        var query = new google.visualization.Query(

        'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ixlanep_0VfZtnk4rzS0jb1owTIbIRWAdGr9mp7OMIc/gviz/tq?tq=');
        //query.setQuery('SELECT E, F, H, I');
        query.send(drawChart);
        }

    // The query callback function
    function drawChart(response) {
        // Always check for error. 
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        // Get DataTable from the "response" object. This is the result from your query. 
        // This DataTable must conform to the data format required by the chart you will draw next. 
        // To find out, read the Google Chart document at 
        // https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/
        var data = response.getDataTable();
        // Sort by the first column. 
        data.sort([{column: 0 }]);


        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw a table
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // We'll show the whole table. So there is no need to set call setColumns(). 
        var tableView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);    

        // Create the table. 
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 
        var myTable = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        myTable.draw(tableView);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw a chart #1
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

         // Create the chart #1.
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the  
corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 

        // We'll show home game attendance, runs scored, runs allowed, wins, loses, and NO# games behind . 
        var chartView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        chartView.setColumns([4, 5]);           

        // Create the chart. 
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 
        var myChart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));
        myChart.draw(chartView);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw a chart #2
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

         // Create the chart #2.
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 

        // We'll show home game attendance, runs scored, runs allowed, wins, loses, and NO# games behind . 
        var chartView2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        chartView2.setColumns([0, 7, 8, 9]);            

        // Create the chart #2. 
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the     

    corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 
        var myChart2 = new google.visualization.
    ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart2_div'));
        myChart2.draw(chartView2);





    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Project 1: Spreadsheet display working</h2>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="table_div"></div>
<div id="chart1_div"></div>
<div id="chart2_div"></div>
</body>
</html>

PROBLEM CODE

<html>
<head>
<title>Project 1: Spreadsheet display working</title>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['controls', 'map',  
'table', 'corechart'] });

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(sendQuery);

    // Construct and send a query to Google Spreadsheet
    function sendQuery() {
        var query = new google.visualization.Query(

'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ixlanep_0VfZtnk4rzS0jb1owTIbIRWAdGr9mp7 
OMIc/gviz/tq?tq=');
        //query.setQuery('SELECT E, F, H, I');
        query.send(drawChart);
    }

    // The query callback function
    function drawChart(response) {
        // Always check for error. 
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + 
response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        var data = response.getDataTable();
        // Sort by the first column. 
        data.sort([{column: 0 }]);


        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw a table
        //------------------------------------------------------------------

        // We'll show the whole table. So there is no need to set call  
 setColumns(). 
        var tableView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

        // Create an empty ChartWrapper and set its properties
        var chart1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
        chart1.setChartType('Table');
        chart1.setContainerId('table_div'); 
        // To set a DataView for the ChartWrapper, use 
 DataView.toJSON()function. 
        // There is a no need to set DataTable for the ChartWrapper. 
        chart1.setView(tableView.toJSON());


        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw a chart #1
        //------------------------------------------------------------------

         // Create the chart #1.
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the 
corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 

        // We'll show home game attendance, runs scored, runs allowed, wins,  
loses, and NO# games behind . 
        var chartView = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        chartView.setColumns([4, 5]);

        var chart2 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
        chart2.setChartType('ColumnChart');
        chart2.setContainerId('chart1_div');
        chart2.setView(chartView.toJSON());

        // Create the chart. 
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the 
corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 
        //var myChart = new 
google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart1_div'));
        //myChart.draw(chartView);

        //------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Draw a chart #2
        //------------------------------------------------------------------

         // Create the chart #2.
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the  
corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 

        // We'll show home game attendance, runs scored, runs allowed, wins, 
loses, and NO# games behind . 
        var chartView2 = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        chartView2.setColumns([0, 7, 8, 9]);            

        var chart3 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper();
        chart3.setChartType('ColumnChart');
        chart3.setContainerId('chart2_div');
        chart3.setView(chartView2.toJSON());

        // Create the chart #2. 
        // Note that DOM element ID must be consistent with the  
corresponding 
        // ID in the HTML body section. 
        //var myChart2 = new 
google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart2_div'));
        //myChart2.draw(chartView2);


        // Create and draw the dashboard
        var dashboard = new 
google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

        // Bind the filters to charts. These filters and charts now become  
part of this dashboard. 
        dashboard.bind([chart1, chart2, chart3]);

        // Draw all the charts and filters in this dashboard. 
        dashboard.draw(data);




    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Project 1: Spreadsheet display working</h2>
<div id="dashboard_div">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
                <div id="table_div" style="height: 200px; width: 1000px;  
border-style: groove;">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="chart1_div" style="height: 200px; width: 1000px;  
border-style: groove;">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="chart2_div" style="height: 200px; width: 1000px;  
border-style: groove;">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the problem in that code?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put the problem code in  the working code works.

Comment: could you clean that up, if the code is exactly what you posted, you've got a lot of comments as code

Comment: figured it out. thanks